# Thread safety with use of synchronized

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading, concurrency, ibeacon

I am trying to write some code in my JAX-RS project. As this is iBeacon related I require the need to generate major minor numbers to store for a given user.

The code to register a user is as follows;

```
/**
 * Register a user to the application. Registration requires unique
 * username and unique email address. 
 * @Override
 * @param username the username to register with
 * @param password the password to register with
 * @param email the email to register with
 * @param firstname the users firstname
 * @param lastname the users lastname
 * @return RegistrationStatus to determine if the method succeeded or not
 * @throws MajorMinorException 
 */
public synchronized RegistrationStatus register(String username, String password,String email, String firstname, String lastname) throws MajorMinorException {

    if(StringUtilities.stringEmptyOrNull(username, password, email, firstname, lastname)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Unable to register the user as a value which is needed is null or empty");
    }

    if(!StringUtilities.validEmail(email)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The email is not in a valid format to register with");
    }

    if(!StringUtilities.validPassword(password)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The password " + password + " for user " + username + " was not in a valid format");
    }

    RegistrationStatus result = RegistrationStatus.FAILED;
    try {
        int major = super.getMajorMinor(true, username, source.getConnection());
        int minor = super.getMajorMinor(false, username, source.getConnection());
        if(major == -1 || minor == -1){
            throw new MajorMinorException("Major/Minor value was -1, possible bad data: " + username + " " + email);
        }
        Tuple<Integer, Integer> majorMinorPairs = IBeacon.incrementMajor(major, minor);
        result = register(username, password, email, firstname, lastname, majorMinorPairs.getFirst(), majorMinorPairs.getSecond(), source.getConnection());
        logger.info("major minor generated for user " + username + "  major: " + majorMinorPairs.getFirst() + " minor: " + majorMinorPairs.getSecond());
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logger.error("An error occured when registering", e);
        return result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now i can foresee a potential scenario where we potentially have an issue. The reason being is that `super.getMajorMinor(true, username, source.getConnection());` performs a MAX on the database table and then increments this by one. I assume therefore it would be possible for 2 max statements to occur at the same time (before a user has registered that pair) and therefore we would get a dirty read/write.

I could lock the table in order to preserve the integrity of the data however would another solution be to synchronise the register method. This would have the same effect as locking the table i believe but would the performance impact be worse?

Thanks

Comment: Since your method is `synchronized` only one thread can be inside the `register` method (per instance). If you, however, suspect that there are other, unrelated operations that could modify the column you are talking about, you should consider letting the database do the job. You know, using a column declared unique, auto-increment, etc.

Comment: unfortunately i am not sure this would be possible as iBeacon has a range of valid numbers up to 65536 before it wraps. I don't think AI is flexible enough although i could be wrong